Cannot limit the concurrency of servlet requests using Spring Boot virtual threads with Tomcat
I am updating a Kotlin (v1.9.25) Spring Boot (v3.3.1) project from Java 17 to Java 21 in order to enable Virtual Threads.
In our service, almost all requests acquire one database connection and hold to it for the whole request, while some very specific ones require more than one. To avoid database connection starvation, we set the maximum number of database connections to be just a little above the maximum concurrent requests.
spring.threads.virtual.enabled: true
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size: 50
server.tomcat.threads.max: 4 # used to be 45 before virtual threads 

Up to now, we control maximum concurrent requests by means of server.tomcat.threads.max, but with virtual threads it all changes: the idea, as far as I understand, is to have a executor receiving an unlimited amount of tasks, so no limits here.
That leaves me to my question: how can I limit the maximum number of concurrent connections on my service while using virtual threads?
I thought of implementing a semaphore but something seems to be off with this approach, I though that it would be configurable.
Thank you very much!

What makes you think a semaphore wouldn't be configurable?

@LouisWasserman by configurable I mean that Spring Boot would have a way to do it like threads.max did, through application.properties, WebMvcConfiguration or any other way. Is semaphore the way to you in your opinion?

It's the usual way to bound concurrency with virtual threads.

If you need configurability similar to threads.max you might look at custom Tomcat thread executor. But then you'll be bound to Tomcat, is this OK with you? What @LouisWasserman meant, I guess, is configuration-unrelated purely programmatic usage of Semaphore class.

Hey @igor.zh, no problem binding to Tomcat at all. Would you go for a Semaphore handler interceptor / servlet filter or setting a custom Tomcat thread executor? I am having a hard time deciding.

If you like Spring Boot/application.properties way to configure things, then there is even Tomcat-unbound way. It would really depend on your design and willingness to mess up with @Async methods and such. I'll post initial solution in half an hour I hope.

YOu can set the server.tomcat.max-connections property. The default is 8192 (with Spring Boot). Which is the number of connections that are accepted. Which is basically a queue (enforced with a specific LimitLatch from Tomcat). You can combine this with server.tomcat.accept-count to specify a queue size (default is 100). You can experiment with those. Or create your own extension of VirtualThreadExecutor from Tomcat, to include a limit (bound to server.tomcat.threads.max.

@M.Deinum, Tomcat Connections and Accept Count only indirectly affect amount of worker threads. Extending VirtualThreadExecutor or creating your own is not that big of a deal. The bigger issue is that even if binding to Tomcat is acceptable, like OP said, the wholesale, blanket limit of Tomcat worker threads might be too restrictive and not scalable of a solution - there could be threads that do not use the critical resource like DB connections, but they nevertheless fall into under the same limit.

@M.Deinum wouldn't max-connections interfere with clients using keep alive? For example: if I have 50 max-connections and 10 clients open 5 connections each, all 50 requests terminate in milliseconds but the 50 connection stays up for around 3 minutes. That means those 10 clients will continue working but new ones would be blocked for the duration of max-connections. Am I correct? I am no expert in such parameters! Thank you!

While recommended way to restrict number of threads accessing a limited resource  is to Use Semaphores to Limit Concurrency of Virtual Threads, Stack Overflow thread In java How to migrate from Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD_COUNT()) to Virtual Thread discusses alternative way to do the restriction - a fixed thread pool and argues that it is equivalent to Semaphore in terms of functionality and efficiency.
In addition, the latter way allows more Spring-"configurable" solutions.
To restrict the amount of Tomcat worker thread, like the OP requested, we could set our own Tomcat Protocol Handler Executor:
@Configuration
public class TomcatFixedThreadsCustomizer
    implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<ConfigurableTomcatWebServerFactory>, Ordered {

    @Value("${max.thread.count}")
    private int maxThreadCount;

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableTomcatWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addProtocolHandlerCustomizers((protocolHandler) -> 
            protocolHandler.setExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadCount, Thread.ofVirtual().factory())));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 2;// need to be executed after TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer;
   }

}

Note that the line
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadCount, Thread.ofVirtual().factory())

actually overrides spring.threads.virtual.enabled setting for this custom  executor - the Tomcat worker threads will be virtual anyway. By other hand, if you don't want to have Tomcat worker threads be virtual, you don't have to - use a default fixed pool for that:
Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreadCount)

Remember, however, that in this case all Tomcat worker threads will be under the restriction of maxThreadCount, even those who don't use critical resources like DB Connections in the OP case.
Other solution is based upon Semaphore, recommended by Oracle documentation, and Spring AOP. An AOP Aspect restricts an access to critical resource:
@Aspect
public class RestrictedResourceAspect {

    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public RestrictedResourceAspect(int permits) {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(permits);
    }

    @Around("within(com.github.webapp.controller..*)")
    public Object accessRestrictedResource(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable  {
        semaphore.acquire();
        try {
            return jp.proceed();
        } finally {
            semaphore.release();
        }
    }

}

The pointcut expression above
"within(com.github.webapp.controller..*)"

applies the Aspect to each public method in com.github.webapp.controller package as an example. It is possible to apply it to methods, annotated with certain annotation, RequestMapping, for example; the only requirement is that the method should belong to a Spring Bean and be public. For pointcut syntax please see details in Spring AOP documentation.
Finally, we need to configure the Aspect:
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${max.thread.count}")
    private int maxThreadCount;

    @Bean
    public RestrictedResourceAspect restrictedResourceAspect() {
        return new RestrictedResourceAspect(maxThreadCount);
    }
}

This second approach is more flexible than Tomcat Protocol Handler Executor-based one as it allows to make a distinction between the methods, which do access critical resources, and methods, which do not access them.

Please let me know if Tomcat custom Thread Executor way is more preferable.

spring.threads.virtual.enable does a lot more then just Tomcat if makes the whole application use virtual threads. In your case you are only doing async method execution, ignore the async servlet api. So this isn't the same, this is a half crippled replacement for it.

@M.Deinum, did I say somewhere in my answer that the property which you misspelled affects only Tomcat threads? I only said that with custom TaskExecutor/Executor used in the answer this setting will be overridden and the asynchronous method could execute either on virtual or platform thread, depending on thread factory used. The solution offered in the answer meets the OP requirements  on restriction and gives him greater flexibility.

@igor.zh the fixed thread pool with virtual thread factory seems to do the trick pretty well, actually. What I can't do is change all my controllers to offload processing to a different thread pool because it's too much work and since you already created a custom thread pool, just passing it to Tomcat seems "more correct". Could you show how to pass that "fixed virtual thread pool" straight to Tomcat? Thank you for your time.

@Heits, please check out an update which explains Tomcat worker threads solution. Let me know if small working demo is required.

My point is that your solution works differently then the tomcat solution when spring.threads.virtual.enabled is being set. You nowhere mentioned the property which would indicate that the solution you provide does the same as when setting the property which it doesn't (by far it doesn't). The best solution would be to create a custom tomcat VirtualThreadExecutor and have a tomcat customizer set that instead of the default VirtualThreadExecutor. This would only need to change some tomcat configuration and not the whole service and API.

In addition to that it also changes how the methods execute and how tomcat reacts to it. You made the application asyncronous which is not what the threadpool in Tomcat does. It would execute the request in a thread including the blocking operation and wait for the result, your solution doesn't (at least not without major code changes).

@M.Deinum, Have you refreshed your screen and checked an update which does exactly the same: defines WebServerFactoryCustomizer to set a custom Executor for Tomcat Protocol Handler? The answer also explains why this solution is less scalable in comparison to asynchronous methods.  You wrote: "the solution you provide does the same as when setting the property which it doesn't". Could you somehow rephrase this statement?

I didn't write that, I fully wrote You nowhere mentioned the property which would indicate that the solution you provide does the same as when setting the property which it doesn't (by far it doesn't). When quoting please quote the full sentence for context. I just noticed you changed your answer which addresses my concerns and lack of context/information, before that I was responding to  your comments.

@M.Deinum   As for introducing asynchronicity where it is not conceptually required, I would agree with your criticism, but this is a price the OP has to pay if he does not want to program with Semaphore, but instead wants to configure things with Spring.

Tomcat is also under control of Spring and configured by it. So adding the customizer is a perfectly fine Spring way of doing things.

I didn't want to distort your statement, the SO comments format is just too restrictive in terms of length. But I don't understand neither your statement,nor what problem do you see in asynchronous methods. Tomcat is under control, but like I said many times, limiting Tomcat worker threads either with Semaphore or with fixed pool is too restrictive and less scalable.

@igor.zh thank you very much, it worked and I think that it is much better than the previous solution. Just one thing: I removed the Ordered interface and getOrder method and it worked just the same.

@Heits, yes, I noticed that too :) Nevertheless, I included Ordered in the code snippet just to emphasize a need to run after TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer. If this guy runs after us, it will overwrite our Executor with default VirtualThreadExecutor; there might be better ways to neutralize the default. I am happy it works for you, please remember about the scalability issue of this solution. In fact, there are other ways, as easy as this one, to solve your problem, for example, AOP Aspect that tinkles with Semaphore. Anyway, good luck and keep in touch.

Raising the number of concurrent requests would require raising the number of max database connections which would add a lot of pressure to the DB. So, for my case, scalability is limited by other factors. If I require increasing those numbers it is very easy to just change the property value, so that works perfectly, even similar to how it was with platform threads. Thank you!

@M.Deinum, I replaced that much hated :) Async-based solution with advised Semaphore/AOP-based one. You might like this more.
